# Can I specify system.codedom compiler inside my web application (bin folder)?

Tags: asp.net, web-config, nemerle

I want to use Nemerle, but for using it :

```
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
        <compiler 
            language="n;Nemerle" extension=".n" warningLevel="1"
            type="Nemerle.Compiler.NemerleCodeProvider, Nemerle.Compiler, Version=1.0.0.9887, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5291d186334f6101" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
```

I need my compiler inside GAC.

Sadly I can't do it on hosting. So maybe I can just use my bin folder for it ?

Can I specify ( somehow ... ? ) compilerOptions="/lib:???" into my /bin folder and put compiler there ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting Nemerle.Compiler.dll in your bin folder

Comment: yes, it's in my bin folder, but how can I show the path here : ompilerOptions="/lib:???"  ???

Comment: you don't have to. Does it still looking for it ?

Comment: Yes, it's still searching it (Nemerle.Compiler) in GAC (looking like so).

Comment: You can add compiler options.  See : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y9x69bzw.aspx.  NCC accepts -lib:<PATH> to search for dlls

Comment: yes, but can I specify my bin folder in the <PATH> and how ? I have no access to the host PC, only my ftp area.